# Lock-in Amplifier Input Voltage

Tags: voltage

Is anyone familiar with lock-in amplifiers and why we would use two input voltages with them?

Comment: A lock-in amplifier is frequency selective. One input is the reference frequency, the other one is the voltage that you want to measure (amplitude/phase relative to the reference). Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-in_amplifier?

Comment: @CuriousOne Yes, I saw that sort of stuff, my main confusion is between the freq and voltage. I guess we just apply 2 voltages at 2 different frequencies?

Comment: You apply a reference frequency, let's say 1.5kHz, and the lock in amplifier will then filter out the 1.5kHz frequency from the input signal that is phase locked to your reference. It will tell you the relative amplitude input/reference and it will measure the phase difference between the two. If you apply two different frequencies, the output will be zero.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm asking about voltage though, not frequency

Comment: A lock-in amplifier is basically a relative AC-Voltmeter, so if you are using one, you are always thinking about relative voltages and phases between two signals. That's what the device does. If that is not what you need, then it's the wrong device for your purposes. A lock-in doesn't work for DC and it doesn't work without a reference. Having said that, most lock-ins can provide an internal reference frequency and they can lock onto slowly varying signals with enough signal to noise ratio to lock their PLLs to the signal under test itself.

Answer (score 2):

A lock in amplifier *requires* a phase reference for the (ac) signal it is trying to recover and it is, by definition, an AC amplifier and many devices implement a [balanced demodulator](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC1496-D.PDF) approach.

Whether the reference signal is provided internally or externally is application and device dependent.

It is useful to see a [test circuit](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD630.pdf) to understand the operation of such a set-up:

[image: Lock in Amplifier]

Here we can see the input, original signal and output:

[image: Lock in waveforms]

In this application, a signal of known frequency (which may carrry information by being [modulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation) although the basic application is that of a frequency selective voltmeter) has been recovered from noise 100dB greater than the signal of interest.

This amplifier configuration is *specifically used* to recover a signal at a specific frequency from within a wideband (noisy) signal.

To recover said signal of some specific frequency, *we need to generate a signal at that known frequency* and therefore two input signals are required.